# How to add another activity (for example video activity) in fragment tabs?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have created 3 fragment tabs. I want to add my video activity into one of the tabs. But I do not know where to start. Should I combine my activity into fragment tab or MainActivity? Please explain. Thanks in advance!

Comment: just change your vide activity to a fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, You have to display the existing Video Activity in a Tab. If so, move all your code in Video Activity to a fragment and add that fragment to the tab under MainActivity.

Regards,
sha

Comment: So do I have to create another fragment.java and add that fragment to the tab under MainActivity? So sorry I'm not sure because I'm a beginner.

Comment: True. You cannot add VideoActivity to MainActivity's Tab. All you can do is move your code to VideoFragment and add it as tab to MainActivity.